# Efetuar ação ao pressionar tecla

Tags: jquery, css

Necessito que quando o usuário pressiona a tecla DOWN (para baixo) do teclado, ele vá para uma div, da mesma forma como se fosse com scrollTop.
Alguém já fez algo parecido com isso usando Jquery?

Seria algo mais ou menos assim?

```
$(window).trigger('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.which != 40) return false;
    var posicao = $('.homeBaixoRodapeTexto1').position().top;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: posicao
    }, 1500);
});
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/keydown/ o Key code do DOWN é 40. Depois disso você só precisa definir o scrollTop ou ScrollDown.

Comment: Obrigado, editei a minha pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que você precisa saber é a posição do elemento para onde quer fazer o scroll. Esse valor pode ser achado com o método [.position()](https://api.jquery.com/position/) do jquery:

```
var posicao = $('#destino').position().top;
```

Para correr o scroll somente quando a tecla down for pressionada pode usar assim:

```
$(window).on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.which != 40) return false;
```

Para usar um scroll suave pode usar o jQuery animate() onde pode defenir a velocidade no segundo parametro da função (em milisegundos). Neste caso coloquei 1 segundo e meio.

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: posicao
}, 1500);
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7mn6W/)

O código que coloquei na demo:

```
$(window).on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.which != 40) return false;
    var posicao = $('#destino').position().top;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: posicao
    }, 1500);
});
```

---

Dê uma olhada [nesta pergunta/resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12404/jquery-addclass-no-scroll/12410#12410) que é relacionada com a sua se quiser ver mais exemplos de scrollTo.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Sergio. Fiz baseado na demo que você postou. Só que quando pressiono a tecla DOWN ele não faz nada. A div `homeBaixoRodapeTexto1` é onde quero que ele vá parar.

Comment: @FelipeStoker, coloque o seu código no jsFiddle que eu dou uma olhada e ajudo se ainda não funciona.

Comment: não sei como faria para colocar todo o HTML, pois o código está gigante, coloquei a parte do que realmente preciso. Quando pressiona DOWN (Tecla para baixo do teclado) ele vai para a div `.homeBaixoRodapeTexto1`
http://jsfiddle.net/felipestoker/3fHvf/