# Adicionar classe a elemento on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, addclass

Tenho um site que no css, têm essas declarações para o body:

```
body {
    background: #fab52d;
    font-family: Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

No link a seguir, vocês podem ver como está o site (landing page). A altura dele é fixa em 100vh.

http://www.jogodavelhadigital.com.br/alvorada-iii/site/

Porém, eu queria que adicionasse uma classe ao body quando o usuário tentasse rolar a página para baixo, e que retirasse essa classe quando tentar rolar para cima (claro que ele não vai conseguir, porque a página não tem scroll, a adição e remoção da classe seria pra dar o efeito de troca de página).

Tentei algo com jquery tipo:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   // código aqui
}
```

Porém, esse jquery só funciona quando o overflow não é hidden.

Existe algo que eu poderia fazer para conseguir o efeito desejado?

Comment: [Dá uma pesquisada no site antes](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12404/jquery-addclass-no-scroll). Essa é uma dúvida bem básica, então, há uma probabilidade de terem respondido antes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atribua o evento `wheel` para a tag body.

```
$('body').bind('wheel', function (e) {


if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0 ) {

    $('body').removeClass('sua classe')

}
else {//rolou pra baixo

    $('body').addClass('sua classe')

}


});
```

> The wheel event is fired when a wheel button of a pointing device (usually a mouse) is rotated. ***This event replaces the non-standard deprecated mousewheel event.***

Sobre o evento:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent/deltaY